# Add custom font to visual composer issue

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I have built a custom class that adds a custom font library to visual composer, and it works except that the icon selector always showing even if i change the library, as you can see in this image

[image]

, on the top there is the icon selector of flat icon library while i have selected the fontawesome library.

> Note: Fontawesome's icon selector also showing in the same time

Here is the class:

```
<?php
if (!class_exists('Fama_VC_Fonts')) {
class Fama_VC_Fonts{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $font_library;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $fonts_list;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $fonts_lib_meta;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     * @param array $library_data Font library data
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($library_data){

        //check if visual composer is active
        if(!fama_is_active_plugin('js_composer/js_composer.php')) return;

        if (!is_array($library_data)) return;

        if(empty($library_data['font_library']) || empty($library_data['fonts_list'])) return;

        $this->font_library = $library_data['font_library'];

        $this->fonts_list   = $library_data['fonts_list'];

        $this->fonts_lib_meta   = $library_data['fonts_lib_meta'];

        // In the 'Icon library' dropdown for an icon content type, add a new family of icons.
        add_filter( 'vc_after_init', array($this, 'add_vc_icon_library'), 40 );

        /**
         * This adds a new parameter to the vc_icon content block.
         * 
         * This parameter is an icon_picker element, that displays when flaticon is picked from the dropdown.
         */
        add_filter( 'vc_after_init', array($this, 'define_vc_icon_picker'), 50 );

        // Add all the icons we want to display in our font family.
        add_filter( 'vc_iconpicker-type-'.$this->font_library , array($this, 'add_vc_icon_list') );

        // Enqueue the CSS file so that the icons display in the backend editor.
        add_action( 'vc_backend_editor_enqueue_js_css',  array($this, 'enqueue_vc_icon_styles') );


        // Enqueue the CSS file so that the icons display in the frontend editor.
        add_action( 'vc_frontend_editor_enqueue_js_css', array($this, 'enqueue_vc_icon_styles') );

        add_action( 'vc_enqueue_font_icon_element', array($this,'enqueue_vc_icon_styles_on_request'), 10 );

    }

    /**
     * In the 'Icon library' dropdown for an icon content type, add a new family of icons.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function add_vc_icon_library(){

        $param = WPBMap::getParam( 'vc_icon', 'type' );

        $param['value'][ __( 'Flat icon', 'js_composer' ) ] = $this->font_library;

        vc_update_shortcode_param( 'vc_icon', $param );
    }

    /**
     * This adds a new parameter to the vc_icon content block.
     * 
     * This parameter is an icon_picker element, that displays when flaticon is picked from the dropdown.
     */
    public function define_vc_icon_picker(){

        $settings = array(
            'type'        => 'iconpicker',
            'heading'     => $this->fonts_lib_meta['heading'],
            'param_name'  => 'icon_'.$this->font_library,
            'settings'    => array(
                'emptyIcon'    => false,
                'type'         => $this->font_library,
                'iconsPerPage' => 20,
            ),
            'dependency'  => array(
                'element' => 'icon_type',
                'value'   => $this->font_library,
            ),
            'weight'      => '2',
            'description' => $this->fonts_lib_meta['description'],

        );

        vc_add_param( 'vc_icon', $settings );
    }

    /**
     * Add all the icons we want to display in our font family.
     * @param array $icons 
     * @return array Icons array
     */
    public function add_vc_icon_list($icons){

        $icons = $this->fonts_list;

        return $icons;
    }

    /**
     * Enqueue font library style
     * @return void
     */
    public function enqueue_vc_icon_styles(){

        wp_enqueue_style( $this->font_library , $this->fonts_lib_meta['fonts_css_uri'] );
    }

    /**
     * Optional - Conditionally load CSS for your icon font as requested by modules on the live site, Only required if you aren't already loading the custom font globally
     * @param string $font 
     * @return void
     */
    public function enqueue_vc_icon_styles_on_request( $font ) {
        if ( ! empty( $font ) && $this->font_library == $font ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( $this->font_library , $this->fonts_lib_meta['fonts_css_uri'] );
        }
    }


}
}

$vc_font_lib = [

'font_library'     => 'flaticon',
'fonts_list'       => 
        [ 
            ['flaticon-world'        => 'World'],
            ['flaticon-gliding'      => 'Gliding'],
            ['flaticon-tour-guide'   => 'Tour guide'],
            ['flaticon-map-of-roads' => 'Map of roads'],
            ['flaticon-alarm-clock'  =>'Alarm Clock'],
            ['flaticon-manager'      =>'Manager'],
            ['flaticon-layers'       =>'Layers'],
            ['flaticon-wallet'       =>'Wallet'],
        ],
'fonts_lib_meta'   => [

            'heading'       =>  __( 'Icon', 'js_composer' ),
            'description'   =>  __( 'Select flat icon ', 'js_composer' ),
            'fonts_css_uri' => FMA_STYLESHEET_DIR . '/assets/css/flaticon.css',
        ],
];


$vc_fonts = new Fama_VC_Fonts ( $vc_font_lib);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out where the problem is. It is this line:

```
'element' => 'icon_type',
```

Which should be:

```
'element' => 'type',
```

Now only selected library is showing.